# Invalid operation after eglSwapBuffers

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

I'm getting 0x0502 Invalid Operation from `glGetError()` after calling `eglSwapBuffers()` with a large amount of commands on the frame. (`eglGetError says EGL_SUCCESS`)

I'm not really sure what qualifies a "large amount of commands", but I'm doing about 2600 calls `glDrawArrays` on the frame, each with 10 or so uniform sets.

It doesn't look like `eglSwapBuffers` should even be able to give that error, Is there some kind of command queue limit I should be looking at?

I'm having this issue on Android with the NDK if that matters, it works fine on multiple other platforms.

Comment: You're sure the glGetError is coming from eglSwapBuffers, and not from some prior gl* call? (i.e. glGetError was 'clean' immediately before the eglSwapBuffers and contained 0x502 immediately afterwards)

Comment: For mobile 2.6K draw calls per frame is "a lot". You probably want to be aiming for about 500 a frame for a mainstream device.